# Do larger monitors slow down winforms applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

Will WinForms apps run slower on larger monitors(i.e. larger resolution) as opposed to smaller all else being equal? My gut says yes, as there's more real estate to paint, but I cannot find any information anywhere regarding the effects.

I ask because we have a WinForms application that generally runs on two 22 inch monitors, but we have a couple users who run it on two 30 inch monitors, and they always seem to have more lag in their GUI than anyone using the 22 inch monitors.

Comment: Resolution is a factor for [fill-limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fillrate) graphics applications. What is your app doing?

Comment: Resolution is what matters, not physical size. The 30" might be 2560x1600 monitors, if you have two of them and a crappy graphics card, then that might be a problem. It would slow down any graphics not just yours.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple winforms app to try to reproduce the issue? maybe it's not the painting but objects in view? Have you tried profiling the app against these larger monitors?

Comment: Additionally to Alan I would say that _if_ you find a performance impact in displaying large windows, you should first check for proper graphics drivers (using the standard windows drivers will terribly affect flood-fill performance) and if that's not the issue, your graphics card might not be good enough for that resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, in dev we only get the 22 inch monitors, so I can't profile the application to see any difference. I wanted to check and see if the greater resolution MIGHT be a problem before pushing for the 30s.

Comment: @JonathanBeerhalter Uh yes.. I'll need to order TWO 30" 2560x1600 monitors to test my application and fix bugs please...

Comment: You mock Alan, but that's what they're running, and that's the request I'm about to submit.

Comment: @JonathanBeerhalter I'm typing this on a 30", they are quite nice for development screen real-estate. Honestly, a lot of the workstations I've seen have very bad graphics chips in them. I wouldn't be surprised if it were the problem. I recently found one of my applications failed on a test computer here, it had a 16 MB ATI Rage 3 from 1998 - ouch. I told him that his computer was "too old" to run that part of the program (DirectX code, which surprisingly worked fine until I tried to take a screen shot).

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but do you notice any difference between maximized and, well, not maximized?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't really the number of inches, its the number of pixels.

Drawing to a 800x600 screen is less work than drawing to a 1920x1080 screen ***(roughly 4x less work)***.
Still, most of that work is likely done by a graphics card, and won't affect CPU load all that much.

Comment: Just a question, but does winforms use the graphics card that much? I taught it uses software rendering so the graphics card would hardly be doing anything at all. I could be wrong, just thinking out loud.

Comment: Silvermind, that's my understanding as well. And all of that work happens on the GUI thread AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Having graphics cards from competing chip makers (one nVidia and one ATI) may cause slow downs.

The application in question might also be poorly painting and it's not as obvious when the window is smaller but when it's bigger on the bigger displays the poor painting code is a bigger hotspot. You could try using a profiler to see what's going on. Visual Studio has one built in now, or you could try DotTrace http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Answer (score 0):

For the build-in winform controls, the difference won't be that much. In general, the rendering of these controls is pretty fast on any resolution.

Check if you are using custom painted controls. In many cases the performance is poor if the paint method is not implemented well. For example if you draw pixels (nested loops for width and height) the performance will slow down dramatically with increasing resolutions.

Another trick for custom controls is to enable double buffering, it can speed up things a lot for heavy paint routines:

```
public partial class YourControl : Control
{
    public YourControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    }
```

Comment: No, double-buffering does not making painting faster.  Somewhat intuitively obvious from the name, anything you do "double" takes more time.  Particularly a problem for any controls that drawn afterwards.  And the reason it is off by default.

Comment: @Hans: I Agree that the paint method itself won't be faster by enabling double buffering, but the application will be faster because the paint method will be called less times! This can make quite a difference in speed with a slow paint method. It does takes more memory, that's also an important reason why it is off by default.

Comment: No, it doesn't affect frequency either.  It is just a counter-measure against the flicker artifact caused by OnPaintBackground + OnPaint, nothing more.